# Wrong math symbols with XeLaTeX and LuaTeX after TexLive update

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex

I just updated my TeX live installation (`tlmgr update --all`) and now I get some wrong symbols in math mode if I use XeLaTeX or LuaTeX. This MWE for example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$. + , - / $
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image: wrong symbols]

I suppose it is a bug in the new Latex2e version from 2016/02/01. Any ideas how to fix this?

---

**EDIT:**

Adding `\usepackage{fontspec}` produces a different output. But it is still not perfect.

[image: wrong symbols 2]

Comment: I believe a fix is on its way to TeX Live.

Comment: That's good to know.

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}` (which most xetex/luatex documents need anyway) will partially fix it, but the real fix to the format should appear hopefully in the next tl update.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually adding `fontspec` does not fix everything for me. I edited my post.

Comment: No it doesn't if you can not wait for the next update get https://github.com/latex3/unicode-data/blob/master/load-unicode-data.tex and then use fmtutil-sys to rebuild the formats, sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: Oh, sorry have overread your *partially*. No problem I was just curious. I'm happy to wait till it is available via TeX Live.

Comment: no I added `partially` in an edit so it may not have been there when you first saw it (guilty feeling made me correct myself even before you replied saying it didn't really work:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove this question from the list of unanswered questions and inform those interested: The fix is now available on TeX Live. Thanks again to @egreg and @DavidCarlisle for the fast response, that a fix was already on the way.