# LuaLaTeX comma issue in math mode

Tags: math-mode, luatex, punctuation

I am having an issue compiling math equations. I got a weird comma symbol with lualatex. Here is a MWE and the result :

```
\documentclass[french]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec,luatextra,xunicode}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
B_{T}&= 0,23\\
\end{align*}

$10,98$
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems for me that the issue would be related to a package update as this code was working some week back then.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There are some problems with `fontspec` as reported elsewhere on the site. Have you updated your installation?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I just updated my installation and it now working as expected. It must have been corrected some hours ago as I updated it yesterday.

Comment: A fix for this was pushed to ctan yesterday but I think it still is not right yet, we need to do some tests and I will report back. Sorry for teh inconvenience.

Comment: Actually correction It should be OK after last night's update  if you use the standard luatex in texlive (I was using the text 0.88 build)

Comment: I confirm the fix is here, thanks @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 0):

Load `amsmath` *always*  before `fontspec`. For math use *always* `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass[french]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
...
```

will work

Comment: There is [this issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290970/26980) as well, which is probably the cause here.

Comment: no, the above works fine for me.

Comment: What is the use of unicode-math? I never had any issue loading `amsmath` after `fontspec`, what is the problem?

Comment: `amsmath` redefines symbols which is not a good idea if you want to load your own math fonts, eg XITS Math. `unicode-math` itself loads `fontspec` by default.

Comment: Ok but is it better to load `fontspec` or `unicode-math`? I suppose that there are some other things coming with  `unicode-math`

Comment: for math _always_  `unicode-math`